# Cannot make facebook custom tab app without SSL..help?

Tags: css, facebook

I cannot create a custom tab app with facebook developer since now it requires SLL.
Is there anyway to create an app with FB developer without giving a SSL URL
Pls suggest me a way if do so
And please let me know about if there anyway to create custom tabs and apps with facebook developer

Comment: Im pretty sure they changed it recently so that SSL is a requirment.

Answer (score 2):

SSL is not required for a developer app. However, once you submit it for approval and it is accepted, you have to use SSL. If it's live, it requires SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you will be using a third party app with an SSL. You can add SSL certificate or buy it from your hosting company. It will cost you about $50 a year but if you have a business account the share SSL is already included.